# How to share weight between two keras layers?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

How can I share weight between two Keras layers, e.g. `out1` and `out2`?

```
inp1 = tf.keras.Input(shape=(100, 200, 3))
inp2 = tf.keras.Input(shape=(400, 800, 3))
out1 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, 3, strides=(2,2), padding='same', activation='relu', name='1')(inp1)
out2 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, 3, strides=(2,2), padding='same', activation='relu', name='2')(inp2)
```

Comment: Do you want the same convolution layer with the same weights be applied on `inp1` and `inp2`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to apply the same convolution layer on `inp1` and `inp2` tensors, then you just need to first create the layer and then call it on `inp1` and `inp2`:

```
shared_conv = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, 3, strides=(2,2), padding='same', activation='relu')
out1 = shared_conv(inp1)
out2 = shared_conv(inp2)
```

See [shared layers](https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/#shared-layers) section in Keras documentation for more information.